# Order of Coset in Quotient group divides Order of element

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

Suppose that the $o(gH) = n \in \frac{G}{H}$ where $\frac{G}{H}$ is the quotient group. Show that if the $o(g) = m \in G$ then $n$ divides $m$

I want to use a version of Lagrange's theorem here, but I feel like that might not apply. Because I know the number of cosets is equal to the index, but I don't know the order of the entire group.

Should I more use the definition of order and start the proof with something like
$$(gH)^n = g^nH$$ but we know that $o(g) =m$ so $m$ must be the smallest element so that $g^m =e$ so we then know that $n$ and $m$ are divisors, but that $n$ must be greater than $m$

Comment: $o(g) = m \implies g^m = e \implies (gH)^m = g^mH = eH = H = e_{G/H} \implies o(gH)|m$.

Comment: Good with all this until the last step where $e_{G/H}$ implies $o(gH)/m$

Comment: It's $(gH)^m = e_{G/H} \implies o(gH)|m$. This is because (as Mathmo123 notes) if in a group $x^k = e$, then $o(g)|k$, and $G/H$ is certainly a group.

Comment: Where I am confused is if you are saying $o(g)=m$ then $m$ is the smallest such that $g^m =e$ but we have $(gH)^n =g^nH=eH$ so then $n$ should be larger than $m$ Where am I messing up?

Comment: But that is wrong, as $n$ divides $m$ which is where I am confused.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Let $H\le G, g\in G$ with order $n$, and $gH\in G / H$ with order $d$. Show $d$ divides $n$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4422741/let-h-le-g-g-in-g-with-order-n-and-gh-in-g-h-with-order-d-show-d)

Answer (score 4):

OK, since I seem to have made a muddled mess in the comments:

Suppose $o(g) = m$. This means that $g^m = e$ ($m$ isn't the only positive integer with this property, but it is the least such).

Now $(gH)^m = g^mH = eH = H$, which is the identity of $G/H$.

It follows that $o(gH) \leq m$. Here, $m$ is one positive integer with $(gH)^m = H$, but there may be smaller ones.

Since $m \geq n = o(gH)$, we can write:

$m = qn + r$ for an integer $0 \leq r < n$.

Now $H = (gH)^m = (gH)^{qn+r} = (gH)^{qn}(gH)^r = ((gH)^n)^q(gH)^r = H^q(gH)^r = (gH)^r$.

If $r \neq 0$, this contradicts $n = o(gH)$ (since $r$ would be a smaller positive number than $n$ with $(gH)^r = H$), so we conclude $r = 0 \implies m = qn$, that is, $n\mid m$.

---

Here is an example where $n < m$:

Consider the group $G = \{e,a,a^2,a^3,a^5\}$ which is cyclic of order $6$. We can use $g = a$, which has order $6$.

We have the (normal) subgroup $H = \{e,a^3\}$. Explicitly, here are the cosets of $G/H$:

$H = \{e,a^3\}$ (this is also $a^3H$).

$aH = \{a,a^4\}$ (this is also $a^4H$)

$a^2H = \{a^2,a^5\}$ (this is also $a^5H$). so $G/H = \{H,aH,a^2H\}$.

So now let's look at the order of $aH$.

Since $aH \neq H$, it is clear $aH$ does not have order $1$.

$(aH)^2 = a^2H \neq H$, so $aH$ does not have order $2$.

$(aH)^3 = a^3H = H$ (see above), so $o(aH) = 3$, even though $o(a) = 6$.

Now $(aH)^6 = a^6H = eH = H$, as in the argument above, and indeed, we see $3\mid 6$.

The reason $o(gH) \leq o(g)$ is that we do not need $g^n = e$ (as in $G$), but only $g^n \in H$.

Comment: This is much clearer! Thank You! It now makes sense why the order of $(gH)$ divides the order of $g$!

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** If $G$ is any group, $g\in G$ has order $n$ and $g^m=e$, then $n\mid m$.

If not, then $$m=qn+r$$for some $1\le r\lt n$, so $$g^r=g^{m-qn}=g^m(g^{qn})^{-1}=e$$which contradicts the fact that the order of $g$ is $n$.

Can you apply this here?