# Let $H\le G, g\in G$ with order $n$, and $gH\in G / H$ with order $d$. Show $d$ divides $n$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, divisibility, normal-subgroups

Let $H$ be a normal subgroup of $G$. Now, $g\in G$ has order $n$ and $gH\in G / H$ has order $d$. Show that $d$ divides $n$.

So, $H\le G$, $|g|=n$, and $|gH|=d$

If $d\mid n$, then $dt=n$, some $t\in \mathbb{Z}$. So I need to show that $dt=n$ using definitions of normal subgroups?

I'm having difficulties with coming up with a proof idea for this and how I should start out.

Comment: hint: what is $(gH)^n$ ?

Comment: @runway44 I think it means: if the order of $g$ is $n$ (as an element of $G$), and the order of $gH$ in $G/H$ is $d$, prove $d$ divides $n$. I agree the notation is idiosyncratic, strange, confusing, and something I've never seen it either.

Comment: I recommend you prove that if $f$ is a homomorphism and $o$ is the order of some $g$ in the domain, then the order of $f(x)$ divides $o$. Then this problem is solved by letting $f$ be the projection onto the quotient.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Order of Coset in Quotient group divides Order of element](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1182443/order-of-coset-in-quotient-group-divides-order-of-element)

Comment: @William, your recommamdation is useful for an "alternative" proof, as this is a (typical?) pre-homomorphism exercise. See *e.g.* Herstein's *Topics in Algebra*, 3rd Ed.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin sorry, this is the notation I learned in class, I didn't know this isn't a common way to write order

Comment: @eddie: The problem is the extra "$\in G$" . That's just confusing and weird. $g$ is an element of $G$, and its order is the same in any subgroup of $G$ that contains $g$ or any overgroup of $G$, so it makes no sense to specify the group. Likewise, the only place where the "order of $gH$" makes sense is $G/H$, or a subgroup that contains $gH$, so there is no need to specify which group you are talking about.

Comment: Prove the following useful result: for any group $G$ and any element $x$, if $x^m=1$, then the order of $x$ divides $m$. What you want (and the result about homomorphisms suggested by William) trivially follows from this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $H$ is a normal subgroup of $G$, then one can consider a quotient group $G/H$.
Order of $gH$ is $d$, which means that $(gH)^d=H$ which implies that $g^d\in H$.
Since $o(g)=n$ , then $g^n=e$. Assume that $d\nmid n$, then $n=dq+r$ and assume that $0<r<d$.

Then one can show that $g^r\in H$ which is contradiction. Hence $d\mid n$.